# Call link to modal on successful Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

If I wanted to pop up a particular modal currently I'd add this HTML and click the link...

```
<a data-deploy-menu="notification-modal-3" href="#">Demo</a>
```

However I want to remove link and call the modal on a successful ajax call. Somethinkg like the below, but unsure how to do it. Please can you help?

```
jQuery.ajax({

        url: "http://localhost/timesheets/mobile/add-timesheet.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        crossDomain: true,
        datatype: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var jsArray = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(jsArray);
            if ($.trim(jsArray.success) === 'yes') {
                $('#notification-modal-3').load;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

The modal html is as follows...

```
    <div id="notification-modal-3" data-menu-size="345" class="menu-wrapper menu-light menu-modal">
    <h1 class="center-text">Test</h1>
    </div>
```

Edit : I sort of got this working..

So I added the a href link back in. For example...

`<a id="notification-modal-4" data-deploy-menu="notification-modal-3" href="#"></a>`

so the link doesnt actually show on the page then in the ajax call I used

`$('#notification-modal-4').click();`

but would appreciate if there is a better way to do this...

Comment: what kind of popup are you using?

Comment: what framework/plugin are you using which supplies the modal functionality? It's not native JS and not part of jQuery...so you need to tell us. And probably the documentation for it will already have an example of how to make it appear using JS code instead of markup...did you try to look it up?

Comment: Hi, yes I looked it up. It's a bespoke mobile framework purchased on CodeCanyon. I thought there might be some generic code I could use to call the <a href link. I looked through the custom.js file for the code for data-deploy-menu and trying to figure it out that way. But was hoping for the generic call.

Comment: I got it working by using a hack of sorts. See above...

Comment: you should probably ask the developers for documentation to see if there is a proper way to do it, or you could set breakpoints in the code yourself and step through to trace what happens when you click the link. But yeah just triggering a click on the link will do the job for now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this in you ajax success code:
(hopyfully I did not missunderstand)

```
success: function (data) {
   var jsArray = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(jsArray);
   if ($.trim(jsArray.success) === 'yes') {

       // fill up the modal with some content if it is dynamicaly
       $('#notification-modal-3').html('thank you');
       $('#notification-modal-3').show();
       // do some cleanup if needed like hide it if needed
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('#notification-modal-3').html('');
           $('#notification-modal-3').hide();
       }, 1000);

   }
},
```

With the controlling of the modal within the ajax call, you do not need any (auto-)link-clicking.